# 301 Redirect and Mod_Rewrite Rule in .htaccess file cause a Redirection chain (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am re-developing a Wordpress site and the site structure has changed drastically so I need to perform redirects from old URLs and force HTTPS in the .htaccess file.

The problem I am having is that my code produces two 301 Redirects in a row and I need to consolidate them into 1 301 Redirect.

Here is the .htaccess file:

Redirect the individual pages to the new URL:

```
Redirect 301 "/old-site-url-1" "/new-site-url-1"
Redirect 301 "/old-site-url-2" "/new-site-url-2”
Redirect 301 "/old-site-url-3" "/new-site-url-3”
```

Globally Redirect all requests so use https://

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The result is this redirect chain:

301 - http:// mydomain/old-site-url-1 (old site is non-SSL)

301 - https:// mydomain/old-site-url-1 (The Mod-Rewrite rule forces https://)

200 - https:// mydomain/new-site-url-1 (The 301 Redirect kicks in and the new URL is found)

I wish to consolidate the two 301 redirects into one.

Is there any way I can use Flags (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) or something else to skip over the force SSL directive and switch the 301 Redirects to absolute URLs with HTTPS?

The Rewrite rule is always processed before the 301 redirect. Is there any way to defer it and then test if the page is already using HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing mod-alias ( **Redirect directive** ) with mod-rewrite ( **RewriteRule** ) . They are part of two diffrent modules. Mod-rewrite always runs before mod-alias. You need to handle your old requests using rewriteRule instead of Redirect directive. Add the following rules after yous SSL redirect rules or before #wp rules :

```
RewriteRule ^old-path-1/?$ https://example.com/new-path-1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^old-path-2/?$ https://example.com/new-path-2 [L,R]
```